# spark dataframe and design Hbase : one table multiple-columns vs multiple tables one column family

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, hbase

i have multiples tables on an oracle database. i would like to copy this tables on Hbase, what is the best design, one table with multiple-columns family and each column family represent an oracle table? or multiple tables on Hbase with one column family containing all fields or multiples tables withe multiple columns family (each column family contain one column qualifier)?

i would after that using spark dataframe to run some job and querying like Oracle!!

wich strategy you use?

cordially

Comment: I believe this kind of question is too broad for SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple column family (more than 3 column family) for one table is discouraged.

Please see [hbase manual](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#number.of.cfs)

So you have other option[s] which you have mentioned which are more suited for your requirements and your kind of design.

Comment: have you an idea about the best library of query sql like with spark on hbase?

Comment: Yes please see https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/08/apache-spark-comes-to-apache-hbase-with-hbase-spark-module/